# Find value n steps away from target in List with stream

Tags: java, java-stream

Suppose I have a simple list:

```
List<String> listOne = Arrays.asList("str1", "result1", "test", "str4", "result2", "test", "str7", "str8");
```

The target is "test" and I want to add the value before the target into a new list, so the output would be `[result1, result2]`.

It's easy enough to add the "test" values with something like `listTwo = listOne.stream().filter(i -> i.equals("test")).collect(Collectors.toList());` but how can I get the values elsewhere based on the location of the target ( in my example it's just the element before the target )

I tried just changing the `i` to `i - 1` but that did nothing.

I am aware I can do it with a simple for loop, but just wondering how to apply the same logic with a stream.

```
for (int i = 1; i < listOne.size(); i++) {
    if (listOne.get(i).equals("test")) {
        listTwo.add(listOne.get(i - 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at `IntStream.range()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To build on top of **Naman**'s answer:

- You can directly collect to a `List<String>`, which is more functional.
- Also I would do the `.equals` test the other way in case one of the element of the list is `null`

Here you go:

```
List<String> listTwo = IntStream.range(1, listOne.size())
    .filter(i -> "test".equals(listOne.get(i))) // stream of indexes of "test" elements
    .mapToObj(i -> listOne.get(i-1))            // stream of elements at the index below
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
    IntStream.range(1, listOne.size())
            .filter(i -> listOne.get(i).equals("test"))
            .mapToObj(i -> listOne.get(i - 1))
            .forEach(item -> listTwo.add(item));
```